# Single/Double quotes messing up PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, quotes, double-quotes

I have some inherited some code and I am trying to make some simple changes, but the quote marks are tripping me up.
Here is the original code:

```
<a href='<?php echo SITE_URL.'members-search.html';?>' class='btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " btn-primary";?>'><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " icon-white";?>"></i> Members</a>
```

I want to use some variables instead of the hard coded menu items, so I made a simple change:

```
<a href='<?php echo SITE_URL.'members-search.html';?>' class='btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " btn-primary";?>'><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " icon-white";?>"></i> <?php $menuitem1 ;?></a>
```

And the pages just gets munged beyond recognition. I have tried various things, until I got some success (in some places), by removing all quotes from the HTML.  For example:

```
<a href=<?php echo SITE_URL.'members-search.html';?> class=btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " btn-primary";?>><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == "Filters") echo " icon-white";?>"></i> <?php $menuitem1 ;?></a>
```

But this doesn't work consistently.  What am I doing wrong?  Where should I use double quotes and where single?  This was to be a half-hour job and it has consumed an entire day!  Please help...

Comment: I see: `<?php $menuitem1 ;?>`. Use: `<?php echo $menuitem1 ;?>` instead. Notice I added `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `'`'s inside of the href starting with `'`, and `"`'s inside of the `i` class! You need to either use single quotes inside of double or double in single, or just use `\"`/`\'` every time you want to use a single/double quote inside of quotes.

You can do this:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL.'members-search.html';?>" class="btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' btn-primary';?>"><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' icon-white';?>"></i> Members</a>
```

Comment: that's not a problem if the second '-pair ins inside <?php ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>members-search.html" class="btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' btn-primary';?>"><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' icon-white';?>"></i> Members</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any quote related issue! Like bloodyKnuckles mentioned you forgot to use echo before $menuitem1.

This is working:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL.'members-search.html'; ?>" class="btn btn-large<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' btn-primary'; ?>"><i class="icon-magnet<?php if($curPage == 'Filters') echo ' icon-white';?>"></i> <?php echo $menuitem1; ?></a>
```